# Let $X$ be a $B(n, 1/2)$ random variable with $n>=1$, show that the probability that $X$ is even is $1/2$.

Tags: probability, random-variables, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

I found the following an [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83066/171691). But I don't completely understand it.

I get that the binomial random variable calculates the probability of exactly $j$ successes and $n-j$ failures in $n$ independent experiments, each of which is successful with probability $p$.

I understand how to get to $P\{X~\text{odd}\}=1/2$ and $P\{X~\text{even}\}=1/2$. But I don't completely understand the answer given by **@Dilip Sarwate** (previously linked) quoted:

> A more general question might be "What is the probability that a $(n,p)$-Binomial random variable $X$ is even?"  Generalizing on my hint on the main question,
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> \left((1-p) + p\right)^n &= \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\
> &= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}p^{2k}(1-p)^{n-2k} + 
> \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k+1}p^{2k+1}(1-p)^{n-(2k+1)}\\
> &= P\{X~\text{even}\} + P\{X~\text{odd}\}
> \end{align*}
> $$
>   and 
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> \left((1-p)-p\right)^n &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-p)^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\
> &= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}p^{2k}(1-p)^{n-2k} - 
> \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k+1}p^{2k+1}(1-p)^{n-(2k+1)}\\
> &= P\{X~\text{even}\} - P\{X~\text{odd}\}
> \end{align*}
> $$
>   giving that
>   $$P\{X~\text{even}\} = \frac{1}{2}(1 + (1-2p)^n) 
> = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}(1-2p)^n$$
>   which is $\frac{1}{2}$ if $p = \frac{1}{2}$ and converges to $\frac{1}{2}$
>   as $n \to\infty$ except when $p = 1$, in which case the probability alternates
>   between $0$ and $1$ depending on the parity of $n$ (as is obvious without
>   all the above calculation).

The binomial identity is:
$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k y^{n-k}
$$

How come he puts $(1-p)$ before $p$ in $((1-p) + p)^n$ and $((1-p) - p)^n$ but in the other side of the sign there is $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ and not $\binom{n}{k}(1-p)^k(p)^{n-k}$? (This is, the order of the $x$ and $y$ variables in the order they appear in the formula).

As I understood, in the first case, $x=p$ and $y=(1-p)$, and in the second case $x=(-p)$ and $y=(1-p)$. And he simply wrote the binomial identity $(y+x)^n$, which must be the same as $(x+y)^n$.

And, in the second case, how did he divide the following?
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-p)^k(1-p)^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}p^{2k}(1-p)^{n-2k} - 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k+1}p^{2k+1}(1-p)^{n-(2k+1)}$$

I don't understand how the $(-p)^k$ factor divided into: $p^{2k}$ and $p^{2k+1}$ (two **positive $p$**). The first factor could make sense because the exponent $2k$ which always yields an even number (i.e. $-1 * -1 = +1$), but it doesn't apply for the second exponent ($2k+1$, always an odd number).

Comment: $B(n,\frac 1 2)=B(n-1,\frac 1 2)+B(1,\frac 1 2)$ where the last two variables are independent. Since $B(1,1/2)$ is even/odd with probabilities $1/2$, same is true for $B(n,1/2)$

Comment: To answer your last question, $(-p)^k$ will be positive if $k$ is even, and negative if $k$ is odd. So the first term on the right hand side is the positive part, and the second is the negative, so we can extract the minus sign outside of the sum.

Comment: @Barnab: Thank you :) I understand now.

Comment: @A.S.: I don't follow. If I'm not wrong, I get $B(n−1,\frac{1}{2}) = \binom{n-1}{k} (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$ and $B(1,\frac{1}{2}) = \binom{1}{k} (\frac{1}{2})$. But I don't know how to get the following steps to prove what I need.

Comment: Whatever the value of $B(n-1,1/2)$ is, adding independent $B(1,1/2)$ changes its parity with probability 1/2.

Comment: So, I could do it by induction like this: Base case: $B(1, \frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$. Assuming $B(n, \frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$. Need to show  $B(n+1, \frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$. True because $B(n+1, \frac{1}{2})= B(n, \frac{1}{2}) + B(1, \frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: You don't even need inductive hypothesis. Any $X+B(1,\frac 1 2)$ where $X$ is integer-valued and independent of $B(1.1/2)$ has 1/2 probability of being odd.

Comment: @A.S. I got it, thank you :)